# How many unique decks can you make with a deck size of 30 selected from a total number of 263 cards, 46 unique and 217 which you can have at most 2.

Tags: combinatorics

How many unique decks can you make when your deck size has to be exactly 30 and you can select them from a total of 263 different cards, 46 of which you can have at most 1 copy and 217 of which you can at most 2 copies of.

Edited for clarity.

Comment: Am I the only one who doesn't understand the question.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't explain it well. I'll try again. How many unique decks can you make when your deck size has to be exactly 30 and you can select them from a total of 263 different cards, 46 of which you can have at most 1 copy and 217 of which you can at most 2 copies of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, one of the easiest ways to approach this is by cases.

Case $n$ (the general case): You will have $n$ pairs of cards which are duplicated. (in a small 8 card example with $n=2$ that would be like [abccdeff] where there are two letters, namely c and f, which are duplicated)

Counting this case: Step 1: Determine which $n$ cards are duplicated.  $\binom{217}{n}$

Step 2: Determine what the remaining non-duplicated cards are in the deck.  $\binom{217-n+46}{30-2n}$

By multiplication principle then, the resulting number of different decks from case $n$ is $\binom{217}{n}\binom{263-n}{30-2n}$

Ranging through all possible cases $0\leq n \leq 15$ we get

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{15}\binom{217}{n}\binom{263-n}{30-2n} \approx 3.5\cdot 10^{40}$$
[Wolfram-Alpha Calculations](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+n%3D0+to+15++%28binom%28217%2C+n%29*binom%28%28263-n%29%2C%2830-2n%29%29%29)

Comment: Thank you very much. As a follow-up how would you calculate how many combinations would be eliminated from the total amount as soon as you find out what one of the cards in a randomly picked deck would be.

Comment: It would depend on if it were a legendary card or a common card.  If legendary, then it knocks it down to around $3.5\cdot 10^{39}$.  If it were a common card then it breaks each case above into subcases where either the visible card is one of the duplicated ones or not.  It becomes around $3.8\cdot 10^{39}$.  Specifically for if it was a common card it is $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{14}\left(\binom{217}{n}\binom{261-n}{28-2n} + \binom{217}{n}\binom{262-n}{29-2n}\right)$

Comment: In terms of breaking down the solution.  If legendary, solve as above, but instead of picking the remaining $30-2n$ cards to fill the deck, we already know one of those is the legendary card in question, so we instead find the remaining $29-2n$ cards, and we only range up to $n=14$ instead of up to $n=15$ since we cannot have 15 pairs in a deck that has a legendary.  I do feel this is horribly overcounting, and treats decks differently based on their "cover card".  To counteract that, you could divide by the factorial of the number of nonduplicated cards, dropping it to $5\cdot 10^{27}$